# Java PayPal SDK send money to business account

Tags: java, paypal, sdk

I want my customers to be able to purchase certain services in my Java application using PayPal.
I used the SDK. After I enter my ClientID and SecretID, I get a approval link. If I open this, the official PayPal window actually opens. However, when I click on "Pay" I am redirected and nothing happens. No money has been deducted from my account, nor has anything been entered into the business account.
Does anyone have a working code?
Thanks in advance!

When I enter the paypal developer dashboard, I can see that all my API calls are green.

That's my code:

```
        Order order = null;
        // Construct a request object and set desired parameters
        // Here, OrdersCreateRequest() creates a POST request to /v2/checkout/orders
        OrderRequest orderRequest = new OrderRequest();
        orderRequest.checkoutPaymentIntent("CAPTURE");
        List<PurchaseUnitRequest> purchaseUnits = new ArrayList<>();
        purchaseUnits.add(new PurchaseUnitRequest().amountWithBreakdown(new AmountWithBreakdown().currencyCode("EUR").value("0.01")));
        orderRequest.purchaseUnits(purchaseUnits);
        OrdersCreateRequest request = new OrdersCreateRequest().requestBody(orderRequest);

        try {
            // Call API with your client and get a response for your call
            HttpResponse<Order> response = Credentials.client.execute(request);  // Here are the keys

            // If call returns body in response, you can get the de-serialized version by
            // calling result() on the response
            order = response.result();
            System.out.println("Order ID: " + order.id());
            order.links().forEach(link -> System.out.println(link.rel() + " => " + link.method() + ":" + link.href()));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            if (ioe instanceof HttpException) {
                // Something went wrong server-side
                HttpException he = (HttpException) ioe;
                System.out.println(he.getMessage());
                he.headers().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x + " :" + he.headers().header(x)));
            } else {
                System.out.println(ioe);
            }
        }
```

I get redirected but no money has been transfered.

Edit: I just found that I should use payouts. I used the payout SDK but now I'm getting this error:

"{"name":"AUTHORIZATION_ERROR","message":"Authorization error occurred.","debug_id":"578ce67e544c5","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#errors","links":[]}"

I also checked the checkbox "Payout" in my apps. The checkbox is selected.

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: I just found that I should use payouts.

Where did you find this out? Payouts is for *paying out* i.e. sending money from your account. It is the reverse of the use case you described, which is receiving money from a payer.

When using the v2/checkout/orders API, which that (deprecated) SDK in your question implements, you must specify a return_url. After the payer clicks "Pay" to approve the order, they will be redirected back to that URL. On that URL you must show a confirmation page, and the confirmation action should do the final API call to capture the order. Based on this capture response, you must show the result to the user (success or failure), i.e. thanking them for a successful payment or informing them of any error and asking them to try again.

This redirection is an old integration pattern. If using this old pattern, and if you are not going to display an order review step (i.e. your integration intends to proceed with a (required) API capture immediately, without review), then in that case you must specify `payment_source.paypal.user_action = 'PAY_NOW'` so that the final action at PayPal says 'Pay Now' rather than the default  "Continue to review order" (this later is default for redirect integrations, the former Pay Now is the default for ones not using a redirect which must be JS SDK integrations)

Since the Java SDK you are using is deprecated, a direct integration (HTTPS in JSON format, using your client ID and secret to first obtain an oauth2 access token) should be done instead.  Furthermore, the pattern of redirecting away from your site to PayPal and then back to your website is an old integration one, used by old websites. There is no reason to use it today.

Instead, follow the current [standard PayPal integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), which uses the JS SDK for payer approval, without any redirection away from your site (which stays loaded in the background).  That link gives sample backend code in node.js, which is an example only -- those same create and capture routes and API operations should instead be implemented from the backend environment of your choice, Java in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer! Where do I have to change to "PAY_NOW" in my code? 
Also the current standard PayPal integration guide is only in JS and not in pure Java, right?
Is there also a python sdk for doing this?

Edit: I really don't want to create a website just for redirecting.. The user simply has to click on "Pay now" and all the informationen will be showed in the Java application.

Comment: If it is a desktop Java application, you should open a website for the checkout/payment and then push the payment status to your desktop app. Direct desktop PayPal checkouts without a website are both very difficult to implement and also not at all secure. Even Valve's Steam desktop app, for example, essentially implements its PayPal checkout in a website. Do not waste time trying to do otherwise.

Comment: For PayPal payments, either a redirect (old pattern) or a JS SDK integration (current pattern) is required.  In either case, the backend portion can be implemented in any environment, Java among them, but it should be a web server; not a desktop app.

Comment: Thank you again!
So then I am going to implement a website with JS SDK integration. 
It it possible to host such a website on github pages or should it be a web server?

Thank you!

Comment: The JS button code needs to call (fetch from) two backend routes to create and capture the order; I'm not aware of github pages supporting a web service backend